# What to do when I solve my problem in a way different than asked?

Tags: discussion

I recently [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49017610/2636044) but came to a solution that doesn't go in the same direction of the question (In this case, I asked about python/django and ended up using a jQuery `hide` instead).

A user answered the question but I didn't even see if their code actually solved the problem.

What should I do?

Comment: You should still attempt to evaluate the answer, which preferably implies trying the proposed solution. Vote accordingly, but it's best not to mark it as accepted unless you know that it does indeed work.

Comment: It is entirely normal that the asker's approach is not going to solve his problem.  One of the bigger and better reasons to ask a question, programmers can get seriously stuck when they try to tackle a task from the wrong end.  Just create your own post to explain how you solved the problem and mark it as the answer.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm just concerned that his answer might have a better approach (in the sense that it has a better quality and makes more sense), mine was just a "dirty" fix. Don't want to end up discrediting the answerer.

Comment: Well, that is something you should know by now, after having tried to use his solution.  If it didn't solve it then it is not better.  If you have not tried it then do nothing.

Comment: @Onilol There is nothing you can do to discredit someone, we don't have functions in the site built for that purpose. We do have a feature to judge content quality: voting. If one answer is truly better than the other, that should reflect in the upvotes attached to it. Heck, there is a chance that when you post your own answer which you know worked for you, will still get downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

I think that at the very least, even if you ignore etiquette, you should post your own solution on the original thread. That way, people who stumble across your question in the future have multiple avenues they can try, including your one that is correctly working.